# Not parallel symbols using slashes

Tags: math-operators

In France, we write d_1 // d_2 to indicate that the lines d_1 and d_2 are parallel.

I would like to have a "not parallel" symbol. What is the best way to do that ?

Advices alone are welcome.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\let\stdparallel\parallel
\renewcommand\parallel{\mathbin{/\!/}}

\begin{document}

$d_1 \parallel d_2$

\end{document}
```

Comment: Alternative to other answers, `\usepackage{amssymb}` for `\nparallel`.

Comment: @kapple No this is not my need. I want to strike `//` instead of  `||` .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would keep the slashes tighter; for the negation, the specular image of `\smallsetminus` seems good.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,graphicx}

\renewcommand{\parallel}{\mathrel{/\mkern-5mu/}}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\notparallel}{%
  \mathrel{\mathpalette\not@parallel\relax}%
}
\newcommand{\not@parallel}[2]{%
  \ooalign{\reflectbox{$\m@th#1\smallsetminus$}\cr\hfil$\m@th#1\parallel$\cr}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

$a \parallel b \notparallel c$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Very good design and code. Thanks !

Comment: @projetmbc Try also with `\mkern-6mu`.