# Adding to ```\smallsetminus```

Tags: math-mode, symbols, amsmath, math-operators

I am looking to produce a symbol `\Smallsetminus` which looks like `\smallsetminus`, but has two lines instead of one. It should look similar to `\newcommand{\Minus}{\rotatebox[]{-45}{$=$}}`, but the thickness of each individual line will ideally look the same as the thickness of the singular line appearing in `\smallsetminus`.

Thank you!

Comment: Somewhat related: [math mode - Double Slash close together - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/126711/double-slash-close-together) / [math operators - Not parallel symbols using slashes - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/511495/not-parallel-symbols-using-slashes/511496#511496)  (although in the other direction)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\newcommand{\Smallsetminus}{\mathrel{\smallsetminus\mkern-9mu\smallsetminus}}
\begin{document}

$AB\Smallsetminus CD$ $ab\Smallsetminus cd$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Why `\mathrel`? Shouldn’t it be `\mathbin`?

Comment: @egreg Yes. That depends on the actual usage of `\Smallsetminus`.

Comment: @Stephen That is almost exactly what I am looking for. Is it possible to make the lines start and end in the same spot? (Just like the rotated equals command.)

Comment: Perhaps `\smallsetminus\mkern-12mu\raisebox{.3ex}{$\smallsetminus$}` is what OP wants? Of course this will need adjustments for script sizes e.g. with `mathchoice`.

Comment: @SandyG Perfect. Thank you!